# How to set csp.rules for kibana using docker env vars?

Tags: kibana, reverse-proxy, content-security-policy

I'm trying to set up kibana with security turned on but without TLS, instead there's a reverse proxy on the ingress terminating TLS (really a GCP load balancer).

Most things work fine, except some resources refuse to load and in chrome console I see:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-P5polb1UreUSOe5V/Pv7tc+yeZuJXiOi/3fqhGsU7BE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

So happy as a clam I find the csp.rules setting, thinking I can customize the policy which seems to not be designed to support kibana with a reverse proxy. But I can't get it to work! Kibana crashes on startup with error:

```
Configuring logger failed: TypeError: rules.map is not a function
  at cspRulesDeprecation (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/config/deprecation/core_deprecations.js:70:34)
```

from docker-compose.yml:

```
"CSP_RULES=[\"frame-src 'self' https://naturalcycles.com/\"]"
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: If you need/want spaces in the CSP, you can't set it via an environment variable. Your best bet is probably to mount your own kibana.yml file instead. See below for kibana.yml syntax example.

Long version as found out after a couple of hours:
If you get your syntax right, you can set the CSP to empty or any string without spaces, e.g. in docker-compose:

```
- 'CSP_RULES=["frame-src"]'
```

But if you actually want a tweaked real policy, that will most likely contain spaces which is not supported by kibana as raised in this bug report (and not fixed as of 2020-09-22): https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/39594

At this point you're probably better off overwriting the kibana.yml file. E.g. in docker-compose:

```
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
```

In kubernetes you can do something similar with a configmap or a secret.

Also, no examples I found online show a valid entry for csp.rules in kibana.yml, notably this thread with answer from ops (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-configure-csp-rules-for-kibana-on-docker/243025) doesn't mention the need to define rules as an array. So to make it work in kibana.yml, define as follows:

```
csp.rules: ["frame-src 'self' https://naturalcycles.com/"]
```

Final note:
This setup of using security enabled ELK setup without cluster TLS may not be a great idea since it seems very unsupported. Even after disabling the CSP, monitoring UI fails to load with the message:

```
You must enable Transport Layer Security between Kibana and Elasticsearch and configure an encryption key in your kibana.yml file to use the Alerting feature.
```